# How to send empty string to int params error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a endpoint with a int param

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test(int a=-1)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

When I attempt to send an empty string to this resource I get a 400.
How can I get the default value `-1` ?

```
{
    "errors": {
        "a": [
            "The value '' is invalid."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-bb8f5c4f34041e4a9c9ccbc241e711fa-f378875df6f8c541-00"
}
```

Comment: Try skipping the parameter completely and not sending in anything

Comment: I can't modify the page.

Comment: Then try doing `int? a = -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `[Route("{a?}")]` to your endpoint and it will ignore nonnumerical values as empty strings.